# PHP foreach array check if stock greater than

Tags: php, session, product, cart

Trying to check if stock greater than. When the all of different items is greater than 10 stock I would like to display some text "The requested qty is not available" instead of form submit. Is this possible?

The problem is i have 15 qty from one items in the cart using SESSION. The total of stock is 10 if the qty 15 from one items is greater than stock 10, then shows “the requested qty is not available” so  don’t form submit. But i change a value 10 qty from one items less than equal 10 stock. Shows “Your order has been placed.”

```
$array = array('0' => array('qty' => 15), '1' => array('qty' => 5), '2' => array('qty' => 1));
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['qty'] !== 0) {
        if ($item['qty'] <= 10) {
            $it = 'Your order has been successfully processed';
        } else {
            $it = 'The requested qty is not available';
        }
    } else {
        $it = 'Some of products are out of stock';
    }
}
echo $it;
```

**For example (1)**

One items qty 10

Two items qty 5

Third items qty 1

= if possible form submit (qty less than equal stock 10), then shows “your order has been placed”.

**For example (2)**

One items qty 15

Two items qty 5

Third items qty 1

= if don’t form submit (qty greater than stock) , then shows “the requested qty is not available.

**For example (3)**

One items qty 9

Two items qty 4

Third items qty 0

= if don’t form submit, then shows “some of products are out of stock”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if($item['qty'] !== 0) {
        if($item['qty'] <= 10)
        {
            $it   =   'Your order has been successfully processed';
        }
        else
        {
            $it   =   'The requested qty is not available';
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $it   =   'Some of products are out of stock';
        break;
    }

}
echo $it;
```

You can simply use a [break;](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to stop your foreach, if a problem in the order appears.

Just as a idea: You could also use a boolean, if everything fine then process Order, if not give the certain error message. Depends on your next steps.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help you also:

```
$array1 =Array ('0' => Array('qty'=>10),'1'=>Array('qty'=>5),'2'=>Array('qty'=>1));

$array2 =Array ('0' => Array('qty'=>15),'1'=>Array('qty'=>5),'2'=>Array('qty'=>1));

$array3 =Array ('0' => Array('qty'=>9),'1'=>Array('qty'=>4),'2'=>Array('qty'=>0));

function handleBasket($items) 
{
    $quantities = array_column($items, 'qty');

    foreach($quantities as $quantity)
    {
        if($quantity >10){
            return 'The requested qty is not available';
        }
        if($quantity ===0){
            return 'Some of products are out of stock';
        }
    }
    
    return 'Your order has been successfully processed';
}

echo handleBasket($array1);
echo handleBasket($array2);
echo handleBasket($array3);
```

The output :

```
Your order has been successfully processed
The requested qty is not available
Some of products are out of stock
```

Comment: Still have another case that is not mentioned to handle it, I'm thinking about having a basket with quantities of 0 and 15?

Comment: For what we need the case with 15 quantities?

Comment: I am not talking about  variable $array1, $array2, $array3. I don’t think so you maybe mistake.

Comment: @klediooo, i mean a case with quantity > 10 and a quantity =  0

Comment: @AdilRaza , this is a dataset to ensure that is working in all cases.

Comment: The execution of code below (klediooo), this code is working fine. Only one variable $array